# Magento 1.9 - Product collection sort by price not working fine

Tags: magento-1.9, price, product-collection, product-sorting

This is my product collection.

```
$collectionWithRank = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addCategoryFilter($cat_data)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sort', ['neq' => ''])
    ->addAttributeToSort('sort', 'asc')
    ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc');
    $collectionWithRank->load();

$collectionWithoutRank = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addCategoryFilter($cat_data)
    // ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'image', 'collect', 'url_key', 'sort'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sort', ['null' => true])
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
    ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc');
    $collectionWithoutRank->load();

$merged_ids = array_merge($collectionWithRankids, $collectionWithoutRankids);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $merged_ids))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(e.entity_id, ' . implode(',', $merged_ids).')'));

if($sortby = "price_h_to_l"){
    $collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc');
}
```

Above code affecting the product collection, where the price sort results are as below.

- Product 1 - $7000
- Product 2 - $6800
- Product 3 - $5000
- Product 4 - $200
- Product 5 - $4800

The order by is not as expected.

Can anyone help to sort out this?.

Comment: can you add a `Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__toString());` right after `$collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc');` and check the sort order of the statement?

Comment: I have reviewed the SQL statement where it's order by is "ORDER BY `price_index`.`min_price` desc".

It's 'price' or 'min_price'?.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly as your SQL statement shows. `addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc')` is setting the sort order for `min_price` on the  table `catalog_product_index_price`.

If you want to sort by another `price` you may use the following code (instead of the `addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc')` line):

```
//sort for example by final price (that's the frontend price before applying specific price rules)
//you can try to add like this also 'price' 
$collection->addPriceData();
$collection->getSelect()->order("final_price desc"); //or "price_index.final_price desc" if you get an error without the table alias
```

I hope that helps

Comment: This is the issue I got on var/report. How to proceed further?.

a:5:{i:0;s:1892:"SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(<<--ENTITY IDS-->>)) ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT 10

";i:1;s:3335:"#0 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

Comment: is that the output of  `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $merged_ids))->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addPriceData(); $collection->getSelect()->order("price desc");`? It looks like there are missing the price table joins which should be added by `addPriceData()`

Comment: Now I don't get any issues, but the result is still the same. The price sort is not as expected.

Comment: Did you sort by final price? If yes aand the result is the same check the content of you price index table, the collection works on that and the sql should sort correctly. Compare the data from price index table with product price attribure. Maybe the price index is not up to date. There might be also some final price calculation based on catalog price rules in your data

Comment: By the way: what is the price in your output? Which method do you call on the collection item?

Comment: $collection->getItems(); this is method. The price is listed randomly not DESC or ASV.

Comment: Ok, from that what I have seen I can't say more. The SQL you have posted in your comment can't sort anything by price since there is no price field. What data is in an item you get with `$collection->getItems();` is also not clear. I would check the sql against database and then try to find out what happens. Good luck